# In this proof, why is $\gamma[N]$ a proper subset of R/M?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

I have highlighted what I do not get in red:

[image]

I need that $\gamma[N]$ is a proper subset of $R/M$. Why is it that we have this? I get that $\{0+M\}$ is a proper subset of $\gamma[N]$, since the canonical homomorphism takes elements to the coset they belong in, in the partition of cosets "generated" by M. And since M is a proper subset of N, there must be an alement in N not in M, and this element is not in the coset $0+M$, and hence $\{0+M\}$ is properly contained in $\gamma[N]$.

But why is $\gamma[N]$
 properly contained in R/M? I mean, **why can we not have the situation that $N$ is properly contained in R, but N still contains an element in each of the cosets "generated" by M, and so that $\gamma[N]=R/M$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosets of $M$ partition $R$ and because $M \subset N$, $N$ is a union of cosets of $M$ (because $N$ is a group under addition that contains $M$ as a subgroup). It follows that if $N$ contains a representative of every coset of $M$, then it contains every element of $R$, i.e., it is equal to $R$ and hence not a proper ideal.

Comment: "The cosets of M partition R and because M⊂N, N is a union of cosets of M. " Why must N be a union of cosets, why can't it just contain M, and some representations from cosets?

Comment: I have expanded the answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, thank you very much for the help!